# No response from generic handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have problem in my AjaxHandler.ashx becouse the context.Request["Action"] is null when I send it using JQuery call can someone help me

Note: I'm using html controller not asp,net server controller

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {

            /*var skill = $("#ddlSkills option:selected").val();
            var types = $("#ddlTypes option:selected").val();
            var topics = $("#ddlTopics option:selected").val();
            var sortBy = $("#ddlSortBy option:selected").val();
            */
            $.ajax({
                url: "../ideapark/DesktopModules/ResourcesFilter/AjaxHandler.ashx",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=uft-8",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        //t ajax handler recollection of resources.
                        //U NEED TDESERIALIZE 
                        var resID = data.response[i].ID;
                        var summary = data.response[i].Summary;
                        var pageID = data.response[i].PageID;
                        var name = data.response[i].Name;
                        var createdOn = data.response[i].CreatedOn
                        var Total = data.response[i].Total;
                    }
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
/// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AjaxHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class AjaxHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
           //context.Response.Write("Hello World");

           string response = "";
          string var =  context.Request["Action"].ToString();
           switch (context.Request["Action"])
           {
               case "ResponseFilterSearch":
                   response += "{";


                   Dictionary<string, Object> jsonObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                   string skill = context.Request["Skill"].ToString();
                   string type = context.Request["Type"].ToString();
                   string focus = context.Request["focus"].ToString();
                   string keyword = context.Request["Keyword"];
                   string sortby = context.Request["SortBy"];
                   string pageNumber = context.Request["pagenumber"];

                   SqlDataProvider sqlConn = new SqlDataProvider();

                   DataSet dsResults = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(sqlConn.ConnectionString, "spResourceSearch", skill, type, focus, keyword, sortby, pageNumber);

                   foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dsResults.Tables[0].Rows)
                   {
                       response += "\"ID\":" + "\"" + row["Id"].ToString() + "\"";
                       response += "\"Summary\":" + "\"" + row["summary"].ToString() + "\"";
                       response += "\"PageID\":" + "\"" + row["pageId"].ToString() + "\"";
                       response += "\"Name\":" + "\"" + row["name"].ToString() + "\"";
                       response += "\"CreatedOn\":" + "\"" + row["createdOn"].ToString() + "\"";
                       response += "\"Total\":" + "\"" + row["total"].ToString() + "\"";

                   }



                   response += "}";

                   break;

           }

           //this returns a json string

           context.Response.Write(response);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up `contentType` and `dataType`.

`contentType` represents the the content type of the request body(that is the data you're sending to the server), which you've set to json which is not what `$('form').serialize()` will produce. `$('form').serialize()` produces data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is the default in $.ajax.

Now `dataType` is the content type of the response body(which is the data you receive from the server) which from your code should be json.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../ideapark/DesktopModules/ResourcesFilter/AjaxHandler.ashx",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
    ...
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    ....
    }
});
```