# Ajax call with contentType: 'application/json' not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, content-type

I have an ajax call, that sends form data to a php function. Since I read a lot that using `contentType: 'application/json'` is best practice I wanted to give it a try as well. But unfortunately my script doesn't return anything when I use it. If I remove it, the script does what it is supposed to do.

Do you have any idea what the reason might be and why? Thank you!

```
$('#Form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var content = $(this).serialize() + "&ajax=1";

            $.ajax('app/class/controller/contactForm.php', {
              type: "POST",
              //contentType: 'application/json',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: content,
              success: function(result) {
                  console.log(result);
              }
            });
        })
```

and my PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === '1') {
    echo json_encode(validateForm($_POST));
}
```

Comment: If it's working without it, why do you feel a need to add it ?

Comment: Kind of similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194251/no-response-from-generic-handler

Comment: contentType specifies the format of the data you are *sending* , not receiving. The format you send the data is the normal query string format.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When using `contentType: 'application/json'` you will not be able to rely on `$_POST` being populated.  `$_POST` is only populated for form-encoded content types.

As such, you need to read your data from PHP raw input like this:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$object = json_decode($input);
```

Of course if you want to send `application/json` you should actually send JSON, which you are not doing.  You either need to build the object serialization to JSON directly, or you need to do something like this - [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery) - to serialize the object from the form.

Honestly in your case, since you are dealing with form data, I don't quite think the use case for using `application/json` is there.

Comment: Thank you! I guess this is the root of the problem. I saw some examples were the form data was serialized and the contentType was set. This is why I thought it should be this way.

Comment: @Sebsemillia  There is of course no reason that PHP can't respond with JSON if that is what you want to work with.  It really probably comes down to how you have your available in javascript to determine how you want to POST to and work with the data in PHP. If for example, you had a nice javascript object that you wanted to POST to PHP. It would be trivial to serialize to JSON and send using `application/json` such that PHP could simple decode the object and work with it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the issue with $_POST not being populated. this was the information I was looking for.

Comment: Your answer helped me greatly after hours looking although instead of json_encode I have json_decode as the data is already in json format so you need to decode it.. so this is what I have $rawPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($rawPostData);

Answer (score 3):

The best practice you refer to is about **the server script** setting the `Content-Type` for JSON to "application/json":

```
Header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');
```

This is because otherwise a default `Content-Type` will be sent, often a catch-all `text/html`, and this could lead to an incomprehension with the client.

If you do **not** specify yourself a Content-Type in the jQuery request, jQuery will determine the most appropriate one. The problem here is that you were sending a **POST form**, for which the default `Content-Type` set by [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which tells PHP to decode the data as POST fields and populate `$_POST`. Your script would have then recovered its parameters from `$_POST` (or maybe `$_REQUEST`).

By changing it to `application/json`, `$_POST` will no longer be populated, the receiving script operation won't receive the parameters where it was expecting to, and the operation breaks.

So you either need to:

- not specify the Content-Type yourself (better, IMHO)
- set a Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`
- set a Content-Type of `application/json; charset=UTF-8` and modify the script to parse the POST stream and decode the JSON data; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681428/accessing-variables-in-raw-php-post-data).

The third option requires [proper handling](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) of `php://input`.

Comment: I see. This could be the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Isemi the comment about the content type is correct.  You infromation about not setting content-Type header is incorrect.  Most all HTTP communications should have this setting set. This simply let's the receiving client know the format in whihc the data is being sent.  IN the case of an AJAX call to a server, the server is the receiving client.  The browser should absolutely set the Content-Type header so the server knows what to expect. In this case because that is happening, the server is expecting JSON and is not building `$_POST` as it would for form-encoded Content-Type.

Comment: @Isemi Similarly when the server sends its response to the javascript client, it should set the Content-Type header as you have suggested. This tells the browser client what to expect format wise.  So to summarize, Content-Type should be declared for BOTH the client-to-server call and in the server-to-client response.

Comment: @MikeBrant, yes, I am aware of these issues; I phrased my answer poorly. Updating answer, even if I'm upvoting yours :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. the link you provided for "proper handling of the php://input" has solved this for me after hours looking. :)

Answer (score 2):

The PHP script should be setting the Content-Type header.

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === '1') {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(validateForm($_POST));
}
```

Comment: Mhmm, unfortunately it is still not working. I just get an empty response.

Comment: You are correct that the PHP script SHOULD send such a header, but this has nothing to do with this problem, which is that, by setting `application/json` as content type for initial AJAX call to PHP, PHP is not building `$_POST`.  There is also a problem in that he is not sending JSON at all, but rather a url-encoded query string as would be expecting with a typical form-encoded POST