# How to send a list of values to php using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table with the first column made up of checkboxes. I want to collect the values of the checked rows with jquery and transmit these to a aphp function for processing .

So far I have:

```
var searchIDs = $('input:checked').map(function(){
                  return $(this).val();
                });
```

which returns an object containing the checked values.

I can get a list of these using :

```
searchIDs.get()
```

of the form :

1,2,3 etc

Now I need to send this to php. I tried:

```
                   $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "update/updateR",
                   contentType: 'application/json',
                   data: searchIDs.get() , 
                   contentType: 'application/json',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(){
                       alert("OK");
                   }
               });
```

However in my php function which consists of:

```
 $json = $_POST['json'];
 var_dump($json);
 exit;
```

I get the following error:

```
<p>Message:  Undefined index: json</p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

addendum:

I changed the ajax to

```
                   $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "update/updateR",
                   contentType: 'application/json',
                   data:{ searchIDs : searchIDs.get() },                        
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(){
                       alert("OK");
                   }
               });
```

but I'm getting the same error and the var_dump in the php method gives NULL

Comment: Firstly, `var_dump($_POST)` to see what is actually being sent. If you want to specify the `json` attribute to be sent, you'll need to send an object from jQuery: `data: { json: searchIDs.get() }`

Comment: PHP requires you to send data in a `key=value` format for it to populate $_POST/$_GET with with. You're essentially sending only `value`, so PHP has nothing to process. try `data: {foo: searchIDs.get()}` and then `$_POST['foo']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were using `json` as a key to the data being passed. In this example, `searchIDs` is used as the key:

```
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "update/updateR",
           data: { searchIDs: searchIDs.get() }, 
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(){
               alert("OK");
           }
       });
```

Then you can access it using the key `searchIDs`:

```
$json = $_POST['searchIDs'];
var_dump($json);
exit;
```

Comment: Did you change the line in PHP to `$json = $_POST['searchIDs'];`? What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: Actually, looking at this, `contentType` may confuse things for PHP, so I would just remove this and try the updated ajax above.

Comment: Thank you, BTW how did you know contentType was the problem? - Bill

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295080/ajax-call-with-contenttype-application-json-not-working