# jQuery ajax contentType

Tags: jquery, ajax

I send data from my view to controller

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/registerAgency",
       data:  JSON.stringify(data),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           alert("data saved")
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("error");
       }
   })

});
```

And I don't understand why my request doesn't use content type **application/json** but use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

There are such a questions on this forum, but I really haven't any ideas how to resolve such a situation

Comment: Testing your exact code in jsFiddle works perfectly fine, the request header gets the correct contentType header

Comment: What are you trying to JSON.stringify()? Can you show us the sample parameters to be stringified?

Comment: instead of data try this dataType :'json'

Comment: Here is my JSON
{
"agencyName":"sadf",
"description":"asdf",
"phoneNumber":"1111111111121",
"webSite":"",
"address":{
  "country":"asdfasdf",
  "region":"asdf",
  "postalCode":"23423",
  "locality":"asdfasdf",
  "additionalInfo":"asdfasd"
 }
}

Comment: @OlehKh, I deleted my answer because I might have missed something. What are you really trying to accomplish? Based on my simulation, specifying contentType: 'application/json' won't work - no error though and header content-type becomes application/json, but server receives nothing/empty. Can you kindly elaborate on your goal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm as well a bit curious on this issue as I don't normally use `contentType: 'application/json'`. The way it's handled is quite different from using $_POST, $_GET, or $_REQUEST. Of course, it is in **json** content type.

**jquery**

```
var data = { "agencyName":"sadf", "description":"asdf", "phoneNumber":"1111111111121", "webSite":"", "address":{ "country":"asdfasdf", "region":"asdf", "postalCode":"23423", "locality":"asdfasdf", "additionalInfo":"asdfasd" } };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ".../registerAgency.php",
    data: JSON.stringify( data ),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       alert(responseData);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("error");
    }   
});
```

**php/server**

```
<?php
    // parameters are not accessible via POST, GET, nor REQUEST
    $res = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
    var_dump($res);
?>
```

Reference: [Ajax call with contentType: 'application/json' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295080/ajax-call-with-contenttype-application-json-not-working)