# Passing my Javascript Variable to PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to take my Javascript variable and pass it to a PHP variable using AJAX so I can update my SQL. Currently the function is being called but AJAX is not sending the data to PHP.php.

CODE UPDATE:

```
function placeData(){
        //Variable is caled and input is updated//
        var hour1Data = document.getElementById("hourDataInput").value;
        document.getElementById("hour1").innerHTML = hour1Data;

        //Launch AJAX//
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PHP.php",
            data: {hour1Data: "hello", loginName: <?php echo $_POST['loginName'] ?>},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                alert(result.d);
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }

//php.php

 if(isset($_POST['hour1Data']))
        {   
            echo "something is working"; 
            print_r($_POST); //Check the values here first
            $hour1Data = $_POST['hour1Data'];
            $sql = "UPDATE `$user` SET `$dateName`='$hour1Data' WHERE hour=1";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
            }
            else {
                echo "problem adding value";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sanitize you input, you are wide open to SQL injections. Are you hitting the url correctly? Can you check with your browsers developer tools what the request returns?

Comment: "application/x-www-form-    urlencoded" should be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (no spaces in between form and encoded)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, The issue is with you js code not with the PHP. You can use this link for ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: This is for a small app that I am making simply for practice. It will never be used by general public. I am simply trying to use what I have learned so I am not worrying about security right now.

Comment: its work fine if you remove space "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PHP.php", //Check the url 
    data: {hour1Data: 1, loginName: "testUser"},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
        alert(result.d);
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Php code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['hour1Data']))
            {   
                echo "<pre>"; 
                print_r($_POST); //Check the values here first
                $hour1Data = $_POST['hour1Data'];
                $sql = "UPDATE `$user` SET `$dateName`='$hour1Data' WHERE hour=1";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Record updated successfully";
                }
                else {
                    echo "problem adding value";
                }
            }
```

Comment: From what he posted, the OP doesn't use JQuery. He's trying to learn and a pure js solution would have been a better answer. Could you edit your answer to add it (for the sake of completeness)?

Comment: Actually your answer is fine. I was not aware that there was an easier way. However for some reason, it still doesn't work. I will update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `contentType` as $_POST is for form-encoded content types. You can look at this posted problem here for some reference -

[Ajax call with contentType: 'application/json' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295080/ajax-call-with-contenttype-application-json-not-working).

It is also important to note what type of data you are expecting in your Ajax request and the data type returned by your PHP file. Put `error` callback so you will know what's the error response.

Hope that helps.