# Proper way to send JSON in XMLHttpRequest in WordPress without jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send JSON data using XMLHttpRequest in WordPress:

```
document.getElementById("user_vote").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //action to handle in WP add_action("wp_ajax_my_user_vote", "my_user_vote");
    let action = "my_user_vote";
    let url = myAjax.ajaxurl;

    let data = {
        action: action,
        post_id : this.dataset.post_id,
        nonce: this.dataset.nonce
    };

    let json = JSON.stringify(data);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState != 4) return;

        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }

    xhr.send(json);
});
```

When I am setting headers to JSON `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');` I am getting empty `$_REQUEST` variable. It seems that WP do not understanding this headers or I am doing something wrong.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295080/ajax-call-with-contenttype-application-json-not-working). When I am checking `$input = file_get_contents('php://input');` in `admin-ajax.php` it returning string of my data: `{"action":"my_user_vote","post_id":"1","nonce":"2b2eaea6d3"}` but `$_REQUEST` variable is empty.

All working good with this headers `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` but I want to send JSON.

Why using jQuery.ajax I can simple send JSON data to `admin-ajax.php` and cant do it with javascript?

**Add 1**

Here are the right way to send AJAX in WP:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "post",
    dataType : "json",
    url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
    data : {action: "my_user_vote", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
    success: function(response) {
        //do stuff
    }
})
```

You mean that in this case jQuery will not set headers to `application/json` but will set them to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and all this request will be produced to simple `XMLHttpRequest` with standard headers and `xhr.send(data)` converted to string, something like this `"action=my_user_vote&post_id=1&nonce=2b2eaea6d3"`?

And I do not need to set headers to `application/json` and use simple `POST` request with standard headers?

Comment: If you set the jQuery ajax `data` property to an object like yours, jQuery will convert that to ordinary form arguments.

Comment: @Pointy the OP doesn't want to use ajax. Also, remove ' charset=utf-8' from the content-type header, it's not supposed to be included in that.

Comment: @garryman — The OP is asking why jQuery and XHR appear to have different behaviours. The comment is entirely relevant.

Comment: @garryman — There is nothing wrong with the inclusion of a `charset` paramater in a `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP **will not** automatically decode JSON and put it in `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`.

As you have already discovered, you need to read the raw HTTP request body from STDIN and parse it explicitly to read a JSON formatted request in PHP.

---

Your problem appears to be a misunderstanding of what jQuery does. Probably when you are using jQuery you are doing something like this:

```
var data = { some: "object" };
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "foo",
    data: data,
    method: "POST"
});
```

When you do that, jQuery will URL Encode the `data` object. It will **not** JSON encode it.

Remember, while JSON syntax is inspired by JavaScript literal syntax, the results of having an object literal in JavaScript source code will give you an object and not a string of JSON.

If you were using jQuery to make a JSON formatted request you would need something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "foo",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    method: "POST"
});
```

---

To encode your object as form data with XHR, you would want something along the lines of:

```
var data = { some: "object" };
var array = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(element => 
    array.push( 
        encodeURIComponent(element) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[element])
    )
);
var body = array.join("&");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(body);
```

Comment: Check **Add 1** in my question, please

Comment: @Alexander — That just seems to be repeating things I've already said in my answer.

Comment: I wrote it while you editing your answer :) thank you! I appreciate your help.